# POST data and different template loaded

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very strange problem with wordpress.

I have created a page named /test (www.example.com/test) where I put a custom form.

(This form send data using POST method and it is a custom template)

I noticed that when i submit the form another template is loaded (the template of 404.php).

**Only** when there is POST data, otherwise my custom template is loaded.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Going to show some code, or we have to guess?

Comment: @Hamish do you know how a Form that sends POST data to itself is made?

Comment: @Dali yes. Is that relevant? Nothing in your question suggests you're posting back to the same page. Please provide enough information to answer the question.